# CSS files not loaded in local wordpress installation

Tags: php, windows, wordpress, iis, iis-7.5

So I am setting up a basic PHP site on Windows 7 Pro to do some local development on. I have 5.3.13 running (installed from WPI) and everything seems like it's working. I downloaded WordPress and went to the installation page and got /wp-admin/install.php loaded, but it's not pulling in any of the styles from install.css. Running developer tools in Chrome I can see that install.css?ver=3.4.2 is returning a '200 OK' status. Because of this, I do not believe this is a WP issue but rather with my server/IIS site configuration.

I've configured IIS to run this PHP site on `localhost` port `88` and have installed WordPress 3.4.2 to `http://localhost:88/wp/`

I have not moved forward with the WordPress installation as I'd like to figure out why this is happening first.

Comment: What is the full url that the stylesheet is attempting to load from?

Comment: dev tools says 200 OK? Is the browser receiving any content for the document?

Comment: @cale_b: The URL of the page is localhost:88/wp/wp-admin/install.php and the CSS file is localhost:88/wp/wp-admin/css/install.css?ver=3.4.2 which is the correct path

Comment: @BenGraham: No it is not; I am getting the 200 OK status when loading directly, but it's returning a blank screen and view source returns nothing

Comment: Do you have "Static Content" support in IIS turned on? See http://www.dailycomputersolutions.com/blog/index.php/2010/04/23/iis-not-showing-images-and-css/

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're running on port 88 instead of the usual 80? Besides that; look at your body-output (source code in the browser) and check if the URL's posted there are relative. If they're not relative (i.e. not /wp/wp-*** but http://localhost/wp/) then that's the problem. Since you're not giving that information, could you please update your post?

Comment: @BenGraham This was it! If you submit it as an answer I will accept it so you can get credit.

Comment: @SiteSafeNL They are full URLs; the issue was the static content suggested by BenGraham. As for the port This is the first time I've had a Windows PC in a while and I had a message pop up when trying to use port 80 about IIS already having another site at that port (Default Website) so I just typed in another random port to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IIS install may not have its Static Content feature enabled. The relevant steps, taken from [this post](http://www.dailycomputersolutions.com/blog/index.php/2010/04/23/iis-not-showing-images-and-css/), are:

> 1. Go to  “Turn Windows features on or off”
> 2. Select Internet Information Services
> 3. Select World Wide Web Services
> 4. And check Static Content

I would like to have referred to more canonical docs in the answer, but there's no direct reference either [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent) or [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview) that your static content will simply not work if the module isn't installed. Perhaps someone can chip in with a better resource.